# React Swipeable - how to wrap a <tr>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, swipe, swipe-gesture

I built my own Table Component in react.
i want to add more configuration like **Swipeable Rows**.

the problem is that all the NPM add-ons for React Swipeable are wrappers that would **WRAP** my  component.

tr tag cannot be wrapped by a div or any other html tags but td.

**in bottom line, how can i make my Row component(which is tr) Swipeable?**

here is my code:

```
let RowComp = <Row key={index} cols={this.props.cols} row={row} onRowClick={this.onRowClick}/>;

if(this.props.onRowSwipe){
  return (
    <Swipe key={index} onSwipeRight={() => this.props.onRowSwipe(row)}>
      {RowComp}
    </Swipe>
  );
}
return RowComp;
```

Of course i got react warning that a tr cannot be wrapped. 
what can i do?
**how can i make my  swipeable?**

thanks a lot:)

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it with <React.Fragment>?

Comment: No, but if i'd do so, i'd still need to implement the Swipe event on my own. I wanted to use an exist package which already implement the onSwipeRight and onSwipeLeft algorithm. thanks for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar in an application. There isn't any native swipe event but there are three events that will allow you to work your problem around: `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove`, `onTouchEnd`. Below you can see an experimental implementation of mine for a swipable menu:
As you can see I have created three functions in the App.js component: `handleTouchStart`, `handleTouchMove`, `handleTouchEnd`.

- The `handleTouchStart` function receives the event as a prop and saves the initial X and Y positions
- The `handleTouchMove` function receives again the event as a prop  and finds the difference between the current and the initial position.
- Finally the `handleTouchEnd` function checks the X and Y differences and displays or hides the menu.

**Unfortunately you cannot access the last position from the onTouchEnd event and that's why you have to use the onTouchMove event.**

**You also have to check that very little vertical movement has happened. That is why i also check the difference between the Y position but you need the absolute value**

**If the X difference is negative that means that you moved left. If the X difference is positive that means that you moved right.**

**You also have to do a lot of tests in different devices to define the ideal difference between the initial and final X position**

Finally I pass the functions as props to the component and bind these to the three events.

**App.js ( parent component)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Header from "components/Header";
import Navbar from "components/Navbar";
import SideMenu from "components/SideMenu";
import MainContent from "components/Content";

const AppWrapper = styled.section`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70px auto;
  @media (max-width: 884px) {
    grid-template-columns: 60vw auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 885px) {
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  }
`;

class App extends Component {
  swipe = {
    firstPositionX: null,
    firstPositionY: null,
    positionDifferenceX: null,
    positionDifferenceY: null
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sideMenuDisplay: window.innerWidth >= 885 ? true : false
      // movement: -60
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateSideMenuDisplay);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateSideMenuDisplay);
  }

  updateSideMenuDisplay = () => {
    this.setState({ sideMenuDisplay: window.innerWidth >= 885 ? true : false });
  };

  toggleSideMenu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      sideMenuDisplay: !prevState.sideMenuDisplay
    }));
  };



  handleTouchStart = e => {
    this.swipe.firstPositionX = e.touches[0].screenX;
    this.swipe.firstPositionY = e.touches[0].screenY;
  };

  handleTouchMove = e => {
    this.swipe.positionDifferenceX =
      e.touches[0].screenX - this.swipe.firstPositionX;
    this.swipe.positionDifferenceY =
      e.touches[0].screenY - this.swipe.firstPositionY;
  };

  handleTouchEnd = () => {
    if (Math.abs(this.swipe.positionDifferenceY) <= 150) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          sideMenuDisplay:
            prevState.sideMenuDisplay === false
              ? this.swipe.positionDifferenceX > 50
              : !(this.swipe.positionDifferenceX < -50)
        }),
        () => {
          this.swipe.firstPositionX = null;
          this.swipe.positionDifferenceX = null;
          this.swipe.firstPositionY = null;
          this.swipe.positionDifferenceY = null;
        }
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const sideMenuDisplay = this.state.sideMenuDisplay;
    return (
      <AppWrapper>
        <Header display={sideMenuDisplay} />
        <Navbar onClick={this.toggleSideMenu} display={sideMenuDisplay} />
        <SideMenu

  }
}

export default App;  display={sideMenuDisplay}
          onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}
          onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove}
          onTouchEnd={this.handleTouchEnd}
        />
        <MainContent
          display={sideMenuDisplay}
          onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}
          onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove}
          onTouchEnd={this.handleTouchEnd}
        />
      </AppWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SideMenu.js (child component)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SideMenuElement from "./SideMenuElement";
import MembersIcon from "./MembersIcon";
import DashboardIcon from "./DashboardIcon";
import {
  SideMenuSection,
  SideMenuItems,
  SideMenuElementLogo,
  AppMobileLogo
} from "./styles";
import logoIcon from "static/logo@3x.png";

class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedItem: "dashboard" };
  }

  selectItem = item => {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
  };

  render() {
    const selectedItem = this.state.selectedItem;

    return (
      <SideMenuSection
        display={`${this.props.display}`}
        onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart}
        onTouchMove={this.props.onTouchMove}
        onTouchEnd={this.props.onTouchEnd}
      >
        <SideMenuItems>
          <SideMenuElementLogo>
            <AppMobileLogo src={logoIcon} alt="App Logo" />
          </SideMenuElementLogo>

          <SideMenuElement
            item="dashboard"
            icon={DashboardIcon}
            selected={selectedItem === "dashboard"}
            onClick={this.selectItem}
          >
            Dashboard
          </SideMenuElement>

          <SideMenuElement
            item="members"
            icon={MembersIcon}
            selected={selectedItem === "members"}
            onClick={this.selectItem}
          >
            Members
          </SideMenuElement>
        </SideMenuItems>
      </SideMenuSection>
    );
  }
}

export default SideMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.
I figured it out eventually.
I thought to myself what could legally wrap a tr?

The answer was: **tbody**.

I used react-swipe-component to wrap the tr with a tbody node and it all works like a magic with no warnings.

```
import Swipe from 'react-swipe-component';

<Swipe key={index} nodeName="tbody" onSwipeRight={() => this.props.onRowSwipe(row)}>
  {RowComp}
</Swipe>
```

thanks a lot for your comments anyway:)